# ios Open app from Email attachment Image type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I want to open my app with email attachment.
I applied below plist property to open pdf file into my app and it works.
[image: For pdf]
Not showing my app name in popup when long press png email attachment.  [image: imported types][image: Document Types]
Is this correct method or i have to use extensions? if yes which extension?